# Error in Move function when upload file in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

```
foreach($messages as $singleMsg) {
    if ($uploadedFile) {
         $selectedMessageReply = MessageReply::where('msg_id', $singleMsg)->first();
         $selectedMessageReply->is_attachment = 1;
         $selectedMessageReply->save();
         $extension = $uploadedFile->getClientOriginalExtension();
         $uploadedFile->move($pathToFile.$singleMsg, $selectedMessageReply->id . '.' . $extension);
   }
}
```

This code works file if without loop and work with single object but when I use this code inside loop , the `move` function gives `The file "app.zip" was not uploaded due to an unknown error.`, so What is the problem and how to fix it ?

Comment: what do  you get on var_dump($uploadedFiles) ??

Comment: that means you are getting the files name and path there ??

Comment: yes, I got all info about them , but I can't upload them

Comment: did you check your folder permission ?? The folder permission should be 0777 or 0755.

Comment: Yes I set the 0777 permission

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38826546/laravel-5-2-the-file-cover-jpg-was-not-uploaded-due-to-an-unknown-error/42298811#42298811