# Laravel 5.2 'The file "Cover.jpg" was not uploaded due to an unknown error.'

Tags: php, laravel, image-uploading

I using Laravel 5.2 and got this error.

```
FileException in UploadedFile.php line 235: The file "Cover.jpg" was not uploaded due to an unknown error. 

   1. in UploadedFile.php line 235 at UploadedFile->move('productImages', '20160808094822_a3f390d88e4c41f2747bfa2f1b5f87db.jpg')
   2. in ProductController.php line 144
```

My Code:

```
public static function imageUpload(Request $request, $productId, $type = 'image') {
        /* Set file destination */
        $destination = 'productImages';

        if ($request->hasFile('cover') OR $request->hasFile('images')) {

            /* Single file - cover */
            if ($request->hasFile('cover')) {
                $filename = date('YmdHis') . '_' . md5($productId) . '.jpg';

                $filepath = "/" . $destination . "/" . $filename;

                $prodImage = new Product_Images;
                $prodImage->productId = $productId;
                $prodImage->imagePath = $filepath;
                $prodImage->cover = ($type == 'cover' ? 'yes' : 'no');
                $prodImage->save();

                if ($request->file('cover')->move($destination, $filename)) {
                    echo "success";
                }
                else {
                    echo "error";
                }
            }

            /* Process multiple files */
            if (count($request->file('images')) > 0) {
                foreach ($request->file('images') as $image) {
                    $filename = date('YmdHis') . '_' . md5($image->getClientOriginalName()) . '.jpg';

                    $filepath = "/" . $destination . "/" . $filename;

                    $prodImage = new Product_Images;
                    $prodImage->productId = $productId;
                    $prodImage->imagePath = $filepath;
                    $prodImage->cover = ($type == 'cover' ? 'yes' : 'no');
                    $prodImage->save();

                    $image->move($destination, $filename);
                }
            }
        }



    if ($request->hasFile('images')) {
        self::imageUpload($request, $product->id);
    }
    if ($request->hasFile('cover')) {
        self::imageUpload($request, $product->id, 'cover');
    }
```

The Statement

```
  if ($request->file('cover')->move($destination, $filename)) {
                echo "success";
            }
            else {
                echo "error";
            }
```

always returns "success", so the function returns 'true' but Laravel throws an error. But the same function 'move' in the loop doesn't return an error.
All images will successful uploaded and moved.

Comment: Same problem with me, did you find the solution?

Comment: you are not giving complete path that's why its not working.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue because I was not giving the complete path to the destination folder

```
if (Input::file('product_image')->isValid()) {
            $extension = Input::file('product_image')->getClientOriginalExtension(); // getting image extension
            $fileName = $unique_prefix . rand(11111,99999).'.'.$extension; // renameing image
            Input::file('product_image')->move(public_path().$destinationPath, $fileName); // uploading file to given path
            dd(public_path().$destinationPath);
        }
```